# Ubuntu Gnome vs. Ubuntu

Tags: windows

When I tried to install Ubuntu by using a flashdrive on windows, I didn't get a dual installation option. I could either replace windows, or click something else. So I clicked something else, and made the partitions. However when I tried restarting the computer wouldn't load Ubuntu. It was just stuck on a black screen. So when I did a hard shutdown and restart, it took me back to the original installations screen. When I ran through all the steps again, I got the option of replacing Ubuntu with Ubuntu. I tried that and got the same results. Came back to the installation screen. I decides to try installing Ubuntu alongside Ubuntu. That didn't work either. Now the only options are too delete everything on the hard drive and install Ubuntu or something else. So now I have two copies of Ubuntu and (hopefully) one copy of windows. How can I get both of them (one of each) to run on the same machine from this point.

Comment: Options during install are limited to the options that are possible. "Along side" means you have a partition marked as "unallocated space". If you do not it does not show up.

Comment: re-installing is not the fix for a black screen. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: OK, but do you know how I can delete one version of Ubuntu, so I only have one left

Answer (score 0):

Something else is the correct option if you want to dual boot ubuntu with some other OS.
if you can try ubuntu with the bootable USB stick,then you can try to reinstall it.while installing it delete the partition which you install ubuntu last time and recreate it.

as you mentioned that step was also failed try pressing left shift while booting.that will lead you to the grub menu if the installation was correct.if you proceed to that one then select advanced option(recovery mode) like something from the menu.then you can try on variuos options there.

correct way to dual boot ubuntu with windows [here](http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/)